# Determining the big-O runtime of the loop?

Tags: python, big-o

Q. What is the worst-case big-oh runtime of the following, in terms of N? Assume x is a positive integer where N = math.log(x, 2).

```
def bigOh(x):
    c = 1
    while (x > 0) :
        (x, c) = (x // 42, c + 1)
    x = 1
    while (x ** 2 < c) :
        x += 1
    return x
```

I'm having trouble computing the number of steps involved the second while loop. The first one should execute a `log x / log 42` number of times i.e. in `O(N).`

For the second loop, the check `(x + n) ** 2 < c` is made each time, where n is the nth iteration, but I'm pretty much stuck after this.

Can anyone please help?

**Edit:** The first loop runs in O(N) instead of O(log N) as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: You may like the compact style of one-lining your `while` statements, but they make it harder for us to grasp your code to review it. At first I thought you had a syntax error until I saw the ':' buried in the middle of those lines. Please reformat using standard indented body for your `while` statements. I know it sounds like a nitpick, but you will get better response on SO if you post sample code that people can grasp quickly and easily.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have reformatted the code snippet.

Comment: Hint: `while x ** 2 < c:` will loop the same number of times as `while x  < sqrt(c):`

Comment: BTW, none of those parentheses in the body of your function are required, they just add visual clutter to the code. I guess if you're coming to Python from another language it may look a bit weird to not have parentheses around the condition expression in `while` or `if` statements, but you should try to get used to the Python way. ;)

Comment: Other hint: You originally state that N = log(x), so log x / log 42 is proportional to N, not log(N).

Comment: In the first loop, `c` counts the number of loops, so it's proportional to N. The second loop runs sqrt(c) times, so we have a total of O(N+sqrt(N))

Comment: Thank You. I am working out the exercises from CMU's 112 course independently and copied the code as is. I had stopped using the parentheses as soon as the IDE complained for the first time and got used to it since. :-) I think the second loop runs in `n = sqrt(1 + kN) - 2 ** N` steps (`n > 0` therefore the square root should be larger) which means the overall complexity of the code would be `O(N)`. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't see where you're getting that `- 2 ** N` term from. But anyway, O(N+sqrt(N))  would normally be written as O(N), since the N term swamps the sqrt(N) term.

Comment: I had used the following reasoning: `x + n  = sqrt(c)
=> n = sqrt(c) - x
=> n = sqrt(1 + kN) - 2 ** N `

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first loop executes `log x / log 42` times. In terms of `N = log x / log 2`, that's just `O(N)` time.

After the first loop, `c ~ O(log x)`.
The second loop terminates when `x ~ sqrt(c)`. Thus it should loop around `sqrt(c)` times, which is `O(sqrt(log x)) = O(sqrt(N))`.
Therefore the total running time of `bigOh` is `O(N + sqrt(N)) = O(N)`.